# Reading xml with JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have a XML like that

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<data-set>
    <record>
        <TARIH>data</TARIH>
        <GUNLER>data</GUNLER>
        <YEMEK1>data</YEMEK1>
        <YEMEK2>data</YEMEK2>       
    </record>
    <record>
        <TARIH>data</TARIH>
        <GUNLER>data</GUNLER>
        <YEMEK1>data</YEMEK1>
        <YEMEK2>data</YEMEK2>   
    </record>
</data-set>
```

And I want to parse it with JAXB in Java. This is my DataSet class.

```
@XmlRootElement(name="data-set")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class DataSet {
    @XmlElement(name="record")
    private List<Record> records = null;
    public List<Record> getRecords(){
        return records;
    }

    public void setRecords(List<Record> records){
        this.records = records;
    }
}
```

And this is my Record class.

```
@XmlRootElement(name="record")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Record {
    String TARIH,GUNLER,YEMEK1,ANAYEMEK1,ANAYEMEK2,YEMEK3,YEMEK4,SALATBAR1,SALATBAR2,SALATBAR3,SALATBAR4,SALATBAR5;

    //getters and setters//
```

I try something like that.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException {
        File file = new File("C:/Users/EMRE/Desktop/YEMEKHANE DATABASE/morning.xml");
        JAXBContext jaxbcontext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Record.class);
        Unmarshaller jaxbunmarshaller = jaxbcontext.createUnmarshaller();
        Record record = (Record)jaxbunmarshaller.unmarshal(file);

        System.out.println(record.getTARIH());
    }
}
```

And I faced error like this.

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"data-set"). Expected elements are <{}record>
```

How can I fix this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Create your context with `DataSet` class.

```
JAXBContext jaxbcontext = JAXBContext.newInstance(DataSet.class);
```

Maybe you'll need to add `Record` as well (not sure):

```
@XmlSeeAlso({Record.class})
public class DataSet {...}
```

But I think it may work even without it.

Alternatively you could do:

```
JAXBContext jaxbcontext = JAXBContext.newInstance(DataSet.class, Record.class);
```

There are further alternatives with package name-based [context path](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/JAXBContext.html#newInstance(java.lang.String)) as well. Just not so straightforward if you write your classes manually.

Answer (score 0):

### Create the `JAXBContext` on `DataSet`

You need to create your `JAXBContext` on the `DataSet` class.

```
    JAXBContext jaxbcontext = JAXBContext.newInstance(DataSet.class);
```

Then since the `DataSet` class references the `Record` class, metadata will also be produced for `Record`.

### If you want to create the `JAXBContext` on `Record`

In your question you created the `JAXBContext` on `Record` since record does not reference `DataSet` no metadata was created for it.  If you still want to create the `JAXBContext` on `Record` you can add a type level `@XmlSeeAlso` annotation on `Record` to pull in the `DataSet` class.

Comment: Thank you so much. It's my mistake but you saved my life.

Comment: Hmm... does SO offer a heroism badge?